# Issue with building Apache cordova app for wp8 on win 8 desktop

Tags: apache, windows-phone-8, cordova-3

I am trying to build a simple app using Apache cordova. Things went well for android. However when I try to add the wp8 platform on my win 8 notebook, It show the following error:
Creating Cordova-WP8 Project:
        App Name : abc
        Namespace : com.sample.abc
        Path : C:\Development\abc\platforms\wp8
CREATE SUCCESS : C:\Development\abc\platforms\wp8

ERROR: Could not find 'create.js' in 'bin' folder, aborting..
Could someone please point out what I am doing wrong!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if you have all the system requirement to add and build cordova project

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html

Sometime if the proper sdk set up is not present this error may occur.It happened in my case.